# Proving that $\Phi_{t*}[\mathbb{Y},\mathbb{Z}]=[\Phi_{t*}\mathbb{Y},\Phi_{t*}\mathbb{Z}]$

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, binomial-coefficients, lie-algebras

> Let $\mathbb{X},\mathbb{Y}$ be vector fields on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $\Phi_t$ denote the flow of $\mathbb{X}$. Define $L_{\mathbb{X}}\mathbb{Y}=[\mathbb{X},\mathbb{Y}]$. You are given that
>
> $\displaystyle L^j_{\mathbb{X}}[\mathbb{Y},\mathbb{Z}]=\sum_{k=0}^{j} \binom jk [L^k_\mathbb{X}\mathbb{Y},L^{j-k}_\mathbb{X}\mathbb{Z}]$
>
> and that $\displaystyle \Phi_{t*}\mathbb{Y} = \sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-t)^j}{j!}L^j_{\mathbb{X}}\mathbb{Y}$
>
> Show that $\displaystyle \Phi_{t*}[\mathbb{Y},\mathbb{Z}]=[\Phi_{t*}\mathbb{Y},\Phi_{t*}\mathbb{Z}]$
>
> Let $F$ be a diffeomorphism on $\mathbb{R}^n$, define
>   $$ \mathbb{X}^i(x)=\frac{\partial F^i}{\partial x^1}(F^{-1}(x)), \mathbb{Y}^i(x)=\frac{\partial F^i}{\partial x^2}(F^{-1}(x))$$
>   Show that $[\mathbb{X},\mathbb{Y}]=0$.

$\begin{align}
\displaystyle \Phi_{t*}[\mathbb{Y},\mathbb{Z}] &= \sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-t)^j}{j!}L^j_{\mathbb{X}}[\mathbb{Y},\mathbb{Z}] \\
&= \sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-t)^j}{j!} \left(\sum_{k=0}^{j} \binom jk [L^k_\mathbb{X}\mathbb{Y},L^{j-k}_\mathbb{X}\mathbb{Z}]\right) \\
&= \sum_{l,k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-t)^{k+l}}{(l+k)!} \binom{l+k}{k}[L^k_\mathbb{X}\mathbb{Y},L^{l}_\mathbb{X}\mathbb{Z}] \\
&= \sum_{l,k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-t)^{k}(-t)^{l}}{l!k!} [L^k_\mathbb{X}\mathbb{Y},L^{l}_\mathbb{X}\mathbb{Z}] \\
&= [\Phi_{t*}\mathbb{Y},\Phi_{t*}\mathbb{Z}]
\end{align}$

I cannot see how to proceed now. For the last part I assume somehow the first part has been used as I just cannot see how.

Please that $[\cdot,\cdot]$ denotes the Jacobi bracket, not the Poisson bracket. So

$$ [\mathbb{X},\mathbb{Y}]=\left( \mathbb{X}\cdot \nabla \right) \mathbb{Y} - \left( \mathbb{Y}\cdot \nabla \right) \mathbb{X} $$

Comment: Similiar question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1084446/show-that-psi-t-mathbbx-phi-t-mathbbx-mathbbx-mathbby

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition, $X=F_* \frac{\partial}{\partial x^1}$ and $Y=F_* \frac{\partial}{\partial x^2}$. If $F$ is a diffeomorphism, then $y^1:=F^1,\ldots, y^n:=F^n$ is a coordinate frame on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial y^j}$ are commuting vector fields. But $\frac{\partial}{\partial y^i}=\sum_j \frac{\partial F^j}{\partial x^i}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}=F_*(\frac{\partial }{\partial x^i})$, so $X=\frac{\partial}{\partial y^1}$ and $Y=\frac{\partial}{\partial y^2}$ commute.

I don't see how to use the previous result, as it is not obvious how to express $F_*$ as $\phi_{t*}$ for some flow.

---

**Edit:** If you want to avoid the "manifold"-notation and stay in $\mathbb{R}^n$, then define $e_1=(1,0,\ldots, 0)$ and $e_2=(0,1,\ldots,0)$ to be the Cartesian coordinate vector fields. You can easily verify that $X=F_* e_1$ and $Y=F_* e_2$. If $F=(F^1,\ldots, F^n)$ is a diffeomorphism, you can consider the components $F^1,\ldots, F^n$ to be new coordinates on $\mathbb{R}^n$ (think of *polar coordinates* $(r,\phi)$ on a suitable subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ for an analogy). Then $X$ and $Y$ are the vector fields generated by first and second of these new coordinates. That means, $X$ is the field generated by keeping $F^2,\ldots, F^n$ fixed and increasing $F^1$ with unit velocity. It is a standard fact that is written in most textbook on differential geometry that such coordinate vector fields always commute.

But now I see that this is probably the core that should be proved. If you accept the notation $Xf:=df(X)$ referring to a function that in each $x$ is the derivative of $f$ in $x$ in the direction of $X(x)$, then $[X,Y]f=X(Y(f))-Y(X(f))$ and the rest follows from the simple and nice computation given by @kobe. The identity 
$Xf=(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^1}(f\circ F))\circ F^{-1}$ that he uses follows from
\begin{align}
(Xf)(x)&=(df(x))(X(x))=((\nabla f)(x))((F_* e_1)(F^{-1}(x)))=
\sum_i {\frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x^i}} \frac{\partial F^i}{\partial x^1}(F^{-1}(x))\\
&=(\ldots \text{use the chain rule})
=(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^1} (f\circ F))(F^{-1}(x))
\end{align}
and similarly for $Y$.

**Final remark**: You have probably no problem accepting $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^1 \partial x^2}=\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2 \partial x^1}$. But similarly, $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial r\,\partial\phi}=\frac{\partial^2}{\partial \phi\,\partial r}$ in polar coordinates (or any other coordinates). That's all what this is about.

Comment: Sorry have you used the Poisson bracket? I meant the Jacobi bracket.

Comment: @1234 Not sure what is Jacobi bracket but I'm pretty sure that we both talk about the Lie bracket resp. commutator of vector fields. In $\mathbb{R}^n$, it can be computed by the formula you wrote at the end of the question. Let me know if you understand my answer and if it is correct.

Comment: My course is generally in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and I think that $X=X^ie_i$ when you write $X=X^i\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$

Comment: My course is generally in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and I think that $X=X^ie_i$ when you write $X=X^i\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$. I cannot understand why $\frac{\partial}{\partial y^j}$ commute but I think that in $\mathbb{R}^n$ this is obvious?

Comment: When you say $y^1:=F^1$ what do you mean by that?

Comment: Essentially 1st sentence is ok. 2nd is not. Third will probably follow from understanding of 2nd. If you keep to vector fields in $\mathbb{R}^n$ this will probably help.

Comment: @1234 I will expand my answer tomorrow to a more elementary one.

Answer (score 1):

To me, the problem does not indicate to use the first part in order to prove the second part. For the second part, note that since $X = F_{*}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^1}$ and $Y = F_{*}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^2}$, for every smooth real-valued function $f$ on $\Bbb R^n$,

\begin{align}[X,Y]f &= X(Yf) - Y(Xf)\\
&= \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^1}(Yf \circ F)\right) \circ F^{-1} - \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^2}(Xf \circ F)\right) \circ F^{-1}\\
&=\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^1} \frac{\partial}{\partial x^2}(f \circ F)\right) \circ F^{-1} - \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^2}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^1}(f\circ F)\right)\circ F^{-1}\\
&= 0
\end{align}

Therefore, $[X,Y] = 0$.

Comment: I don't get it.. The flow of a zero vector field is the identity (for any $t$), not $F$ (?)

Comment: I overlooked that having $F = \phi_t$ would imply $F = \phi_0 = id$. I've made changes that is more to my liking. :-)

Comment: @kobe Sorry have you used the Poisson bracket? I meant the Jacobi bracket.

Comment: @1234 I did use the definition of the bracket shown in your edit. A vector field $X$ on $\Bbb R^n$ acts on smooth functions $f : \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R$ such that $Xf := (X \cdot \nabla)f$. So $$[X,Y]f = (X\cdot \nabla)(Yf) - (Y\cdot \nabla)(Xf) = X(Yf) - Y(Xf)$$

Comment: @kobe Can you please explain why $Yf\circ f=\frac{\partial }{\partial x_2}(f\circ F)$? I was trying to perform similar step but couldn't find anything as simple.

Comment: @kobe I cant understand that step either

Comment: @1234 and Peter it's $Yf \circ \color{red}{F} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x^2}(f\circ F)$. This is because $$Yf \circ F = \frac{\partial(f\circ F)}{\partial x^2} \circ F^{-1} \circ F = \frac{\partial}{\partial x^2}(f\circ F).$$

Comment: @kobe Right, thank you.